# Can the operation of a Banana PI M3 without any heat sink cause damage?

Tags: cooling, overheating, heatsink, cpu-cooler, single-board

My pure *Banana PI M3* board has just been delivered. However, it has come without any heat sink.

The specifications are:

> CPU: A83T ARM Cortex-A7 octa-core,512 KB L1 cache 1 MB L2 cache
>
> GPU: PowerVR SGX544MP1· Comply with OpenGL ES 2.0, OpenCL 1.x, DX 9_3
>
> Power Source: Micro USB, optional 5V DC port (center positive 1,6 x 4,4mm)

source: http://www.banana-pi.org/m3.html

I've got a USB 2A power supply.

Now I doubt if I can start it first time without placing a set of heat sinks onto the chips. I have read different statements. Some say the A7 processor had a feature to adjust speed and stop cores to manage operation temperature. But I am not sure if I should try a first startup completely without any cooling solution, not even a heat sink. It will run only as a network device with a LAN cable and a USB stick connected, no display.

Do I risk a damage when I try the *Banana PI M3* board without cooling down the chips?

Comment: I was unsure where should be the best place for my question and I decided based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198227/where-is-the-best-place-to-ask-my-question) to post it here. Please migrate if there is a better place. Please ask if there is anything I could do to improve my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Do I risk a damage when I try the Banana PI M3 board without cooling down the chips?**

Not if you are using the provided operating system and standard configuration. It will shut down cores to keep temperature within safe limits.

See [Quick review of Banana Pi M3](https://forum.armbian.com/index.php/topic/474-quick-review-of-banana-pi-m3/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you may start the board, but within less than 10 minutes you will see the processor heating up above 65°C (even in idle mode) and the OS lowering the CPU-frequency or even shutting down most of the cores.
I ran into the same problem - even with (small) heat sinks on each of the chips I was not able to use the M3 board - so I sent it back after two weeks of failful tests with all the OS variants from banana homepage.
Even with the heat sinks the cpu temperature was monitored up to 85°C during a benchmark test.
I own also a banana pi R1 which is running perfect (without heat sink) but I am very disappointed by the M3!

[image: thermal image of banana pi M3 in idle and load]

Comment: This seems to indicate the heatsinks are *cold* and there's no thermal transfer going on.

Comment: What @JourneymanGeek said; if the heatsinks were doing their job, you should expect to see the heatsinks well above the surrounding board temperature, because the heat should be moving from the hot CPU die to the heatsink. This looks like the exact opposite, as if the heatsinks were thermally *isolated* from everything else.

Comment: *That*. I did assume that someone who has what looks like a *really* nice thermal camera would make that connection once its pointed out ;p

Comment: Was the image link removed?